# Azure Powershell Add-AlertRule not working

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am not able to create Alerts from Power Shell

Command

```
Add-AlertRule -Name "poor sales"  -Description "slow sales alert"  -ResourceGroup "Default-ApplicationInsights-CentralUS"  -ResourceId "/subscriptions/subsId/resourcegroups/Default-ApplicationInsights-CentralUS/providers/microsoft.insights/components/TestAppIns"  -MetricName "salesPerHour"  -Operator LessThan  -Threshold 100  -WindowSize 00:30:00  -CustomEmails "satish@fabrikam.com","lei@fabrikam.com"  -Location "East US" -RuleType Metric
```

## Exception Details

> Add-AlertRule : InternalServerError: Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.MonitoringServiceException'
>   was thrown. At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-AlertRule -Name "poor sales"  -Description "slow sales alert"  -ResourceGrou ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AlertRule], CloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Hyak.Common.CloudException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Alerts.AddAlertRuleCommand

Answer (score 0):

The alert rules for custom metric cannot be created before the metric is written with **no zero** value at least once. I do not know whether it is an issue or designed behavior.
It was solved by following workaround in my case:

1. Create Application Insights service
2. Deploy Cloud/Web services and initialize all metrics
3. Create Alert Rules

I guess you should contact MS Support, if the workaround is not applicable in your case.